# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'quantity')

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

**shopping-cart.service.ts**

```
async addToCart(product:Product){
    this.updateItem(product,1)
}

async removeFromCart(product:Product){
    this.updateItem(product, -1)
}
private getItem(cartId: string, productId: string) {
    return this.db.object('/shopping-carts/' + cartId + '/items/' + productId);
}
private async getOrCreateCartId():Promise<string>{
    let cartId = localStorage.getItem('cartId')
    if(cartId) return cartId;

    let result = await this.create();
    localStorage.setItem('cartId',result.key!);
    return result.key!;
}

private async updateItem(product:Product,change:number){
    let cartId = await this.getOrCreateCartId();
    let item$ = this.getItem(cartId,product.key);
    item$.valueChanges().take(1).subscribe((item:any)=>{
    let quantity = (item.quantity || 0) + change;  // error
    if (quantity === 0) item$.remove();
    else  item$.update({
     title:product.title, 
     imageUrl:product.imageUrl, 
     price: product.price,
     quantity:quantity
   })
 })
}
```

Error:-
Getting this error in the console it removes the items from the cart when it's quantity becomes zero(products which are already present in the cart) , but when I try to add an item to the cart it doesn't lets me add the product to the cart and show's me this error in the console

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'quantity')
    at SafeSubscriber._next (shopping-cart.service.ts:61)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at TakeSubscriber._next (take.js:35)
    at TakeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
    at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
    at Notification.observe (Notification.js:20)
```

Comment: Can you console.log(quantity), pls

Comment: before I did not have the remove condition so it was still showing the products with quantity zero and still be there in the cart, for the console log it shows the quantity of the product (as there are '7' almonds, the number 7),but if the quantity is zero it throws a null error in the console.

Comment: if(item) item$.update({quantity: item.quantity + change});
      else item$.set( {title:product.title,imageUrl:product.imageUrl,price: product.price, quantity:1});

Comment: used this to add items to the cart before using remove.

Answer (score 0):

I think its an async await issue on

`let item$ = this.getItem(cartId,product.key);`

so item is undefined, which is why you have `properties of **null**`

Comment: No luck still the same error

Comment: There is no semi colon after it - assume you tried adding one? 
Could be ```this.updateItem(product, -1)``` and that you are setting the item to -1, so false and that causes issues - the logic needs to be stepped through in the removal imo. Keep at it / good luck!

Comment: Yes the reason for remove method is that the product quantity was also taking negative value due to - 1 so had to remove it as it reached 0